# How do I validate different users for different SSIDs on a FreeRADIUS server?

Tags: freeradius, ssid

I have two SSIDs (one for users, one for employees), and a FreeRADIUS server which authorises accounts to access the wireless networks. But the server is validating all the user accounts to access both SSIDs. I want user accounts to be unable to access the employee SSID, and vice versa. How do I set that up?

Comment: Is this a question about writing *software*? If not, another site would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use unlang configuration to only permit the connections you want. There are several different ways of doing it. You first need to work out whether it's a user or employee connecting.

This could be via something like an LDAP lookup, or maybe your users connect with '*username@user.example.com*' and employees connect as '*username@employee.example.com*'. If this is the example, use the realm module (`suffix` in the `sites-enabled/default` file) to split the User-Name attribute into Stripped-Username and Realm.

You also need the SSID. Many NASes provide this as part of the Called-Station-ID attribute, so you can use the provided `rewrite_called_station_id` policy to get this (FreeRADIUS 3).

Then you could do something in your `sites-enabled/default` *authorize{}* section like:

```
# get SSID from Called-Station-Id
rewrite_called_station_id

# check user connecting to employee SSID and reject if so
if (Realm == 'user.example.com' && Called-Station-SSID == "employee") {
    reject
}

# check employee connecting to user SSID and reject if so
if (Realm == 'employee.example.com' && Called-Station-SSID == "user") {
    reject
}

# otherwise we will continue processing...
```

Hopefully you can see how you build up policy to control access. See the [`unlang` man page](http://freeradius.org/radiusd/man/unlang.html) for more details. There are a lot of examples on the [FreeRADIUS wiki](http://wiki.freeradius.org/), and also in the [default configuration](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/tree/v3.0.x/raddb/policy.d) with the server.